# How do I save the output or the results of this Python script as a text or csv file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

sourceUrl = "/home/me/results.html"

dataPage = urllib.urlopen(sourceUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(dataPage)

soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "description keywords"})
```

I am copying data from my county's public record site. Some of the counties provide a downloadable csv file for citizens, but mine does not. So, I'm trying to learn Python to do it. I have grabbed all the data I need, but I need a way to save it as a csv or text file.

Comment: Look at your question. Please format correctly.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm a newbie. I just learned basic Python today. Should I just label it as a python script and not a Python BeautifulSoup script?

Comment: I'm trying to save the output from the above script. I want to save the output as a CSV file.

Comment: @user1718373 Your question has been edited by a kindly user to make it readable. It was not readable as posted.

Comment: On a side note you should be using `BeautifulSoup` 4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can save data to a text file easily:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write('text')
```

For CSV files, the process is pretty much the same:

```
import csv

with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as handle:
    writer = csv.writer(handle)
    writer.writerow(['Test', 'row', 'contents'])
```